# ffmpeg low speed on AMD encoder

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding

I'm encoding some videos with ffmpeg, if I use only CPU the speed it's about 1x, so as I have an AMD RX580 I tried with amd encoding, but only increased the speed to 1.5x. Is this ok? Should it go faster?

My command is:

```
ffmpeg -i 5.mp4 -c:v h264_amf -lavfi "[0:v]scale=1920:1080,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\,w)/8:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\,ch)/8:chroma_power=1[bg];[0:v]scale=-1:1080[ov];[bg][ov]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,crop=w=1920:h=1080" output.mp4
```

Can I do anything to increase the speed?

Thanks

Comment: The filters are executed on the CPU, and takes more time than the video encoding that uses the GPU. Some of the filters may be GPU accelerated using OpenCL or Vulkan or DirectX or VAAPI, but it's not simple to use.

Comment: A vulkan scaling filter should speed this up quite nicely. I'll be back with an example.